# minimum activemq cluster size with replicated leveldb store

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper, leveldb

What is the rationale behind requiring at least 3 ActiveMQ instances and 3 ZooKeeper servers for running master/slave setup with replicated LevelDB storage? If the requirement is imposed by the usage of ZooKeeper which requires at least 3 servers, what is the rationale for ZooKeeper to require at least 3 servers to provide reliability?

- Is it for guaranteeing consistency in cases of network partitions (by sacrificing availability on the smaller smaller partition) as in a 2-node primary backup configuration it is impossible distinguish between a failed peer or both nodes being in different network partitions?
- Is it for providing tolerance against Byzantine failures where you need 2f+1 nodes to survive f faulty nodes (considering ONLY crash failures requires only f+1 nodes to survive f faults)?

Or is there any other reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper requires at least 3 servers because of how it elects a new Activemq Master.  Zookeeper requires a majority (n/2+1) to elect a new master.  If it does not have that majority, no master will be selected and the system will fail.  This is the same reason for why you use an odd number of Zookeepers servers. (EG. 3 servers gives you the same failure rate as 4 because of majority, can still only lose 1 server.)

For Activemq, the necessity of at least 3 servers is derived from how the messages are synced, and the fact that when a new master is elected, it requires atleast a quorum of nodes (N/2+1) to be able to identify the latest updates.  ActiveMQ will sync messages with 1 slave, and then respond with an OK.  It will then sync asynchronously with all other slaves.  If a quorum is not present when a node fails, then Zookeeper has no way to distinguish which node is the most currently updated.  This is what happens when you have only 2 nodes originally, so at least 3 is recommended.

[From ActiveMQ site](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html), under How it Works:

> All messaging operations which require a sync to disk will wait for the update to be replicated to a quorum of the nodes before completing. So if you configure the store with replicas="3" then the quorum size is (3/2+1)=2. The master will store the update locally and wait for 1 other slave to store the update before reporting success. Another way to think about it is that store will do synchronous replication to a quorum of the replication nodes and asynchronous replication replication to any additional nodes.
>
> When a new master is elected, you also need at least a quorum of nodes online to be able to find a node with the lastest updates. The node with the lastest updates will become the new master. Therefore, it's recommend that you run with at least 3 replica nodes so that you can take one down without suffering a service outage.

Comment: Thanks - however that does not answer my question:

Comment: Thanks - however that does not answer my question as to why e.g. the developers of activemq have chosen to sync messages to a quorum of nodes? Is it to guarantee consistency in case of network partitions, or is it simply because there is already zookeeper requiring 3 servers?

Provided a reliable network it would be possible to implement master/slave clusters which can survive f crash failures provided you have f+1 processes - which clearly is much less than requiring 2f+1 processes to survive f failures.

Comment: It is for consistency.  Although I agree it doesn't make complete sense in some instances, their default algorithm for selecting a new master requires n/2+1 nodes available.  Part of this decision is due to their syncing mechanism and the fact that you need at least 2 nodes available to identify which has the most updated messages.  I think it would make more sense if they just required at least 2 nodes up at all times, so you would have better fail over, basically n-2 nodes could be lost.  I'm sure they had a reason for this though.